# HTML page pass a Form with POST to next page without HTTP server

Tags: html, forms, file, http

is there any way I can access/get the fields of a HTML Form
passed with POST (method=POST) from the invoked page (action="xpage2.html")
using only filesystem (file:///xpage1.html -> no HTTP server)

Basically,,, how do I access the form information
that usually is passed in the HTTP headers section

I know I can do this with localStorage, sessionStorage or even a cookie---
but that is not what I want...

HTML page pass a Form with POST to next page without HTTP server

Answer (score 0):

No.

There are no client-side mechanisms to read POSTed data.

Comment: Thanks Quentin... I was afraid of that,,, I guess I'll drop-back to SessionStorage....
(better than processing a cookie though!!! ;-) )